# Best Practice for implementing an interface multiple times

Tags: c#, interface, coding-style, extends, conventions

```
public interface IDoSomething

public class ClassA : IDoSomething
public class ClassB : IDoSomething
public class ClassC : IDoSomething
```

I have an interface that is implemented by several classes, there is also a block of code that needs to parse some data and then create new instances of these objects. Right now I have a big switch statement that determines which object to use but there has to be a better way.

I want to be able to create new classes that also implement the interface, code up the class and never have to refactor code (such as adding a case in a switch statement).

What is the best practice for implementing something like this?

Here's what my current (crappy) switch statement looks like:

```
switch (flag)
{
    case 1:
        return new ClassA();
    case 2:
        return new ClassB();
    case 3:
        return new ClassC();
    default:
        return null;
}
```

Comment: You could use a dictionary.. `dict = new Dictionary<int, Func<IDoSomething>> { { 1, () => new ClassA() } }` and then your method becomes (plus error checking/non matching key checking): `return dict[flag]();`

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of when to use an [abstract factory](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md). I put an example on [this page](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/02/23/abstract-factory-pattern.html). If you scroll down to the second code block you'll see it's dealing with the same scenario - I need to return an implementation of an interface, and I want to use some value to tell me which implementation to return.

You can do this without using a DI container, but they're good for this because when they create an implementation of `IDoSomething`, if that implementation also has dependencies it creates them too. So if `ClassA` needs something to be passed to its constructor, and that something needs a value passed to its constructor, the DI container handles all that.

I like Windsor because it provides a [nice implementation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md) of abstract factory.

The problem with this answer is that I'm recommending that you dive into dependency injection to solve this particular problem. But I really do recommend it. You're trying to program to interfaces and it facilitates that type of design. It takes what you're doing and makes it so easy that you'll do it more and more.

I need to write up a blog post that describes it more from the ground up.

Comment: I often start digging around for blog posts that explain things like this well without throwing a ton of unnecessary jargon into it. Then when I can't find it I write my own. (Don't know if it's any better.) What sort of project is it? (WCF, website, etc.) Or if it's just a class library, what sort of application will it be called from? I can write up something that explains it better from the ground up, rather than me throwing out an idea and not fully explaining/showing it.